# YADCF initial select latest value

Tags: yadcf

I woud like to select the first value from YADCF selector at page load. I can do this manually:

```
yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [
    // 1 being the column number, and "value" being the value you want it to initially search for when page loads
    [4, "3/2020"]
```

...but it is possible to automatically select the most recent value (3/2020 in the example)?

[image]

Comment: No, that is not possibly

Comment: @Daniel that's not good. Any workaround? I thought something like this should work: yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [ [4, $("#yadcf-filter--mytable-4 option:eq(1)").val()] ]) -> eq(1) to get the second option in a select. This would be enough for me.

Comment: You asked for a "yadcf" way... of course you can find some workaround, post a jsfiddle and I'll try to help you with a workaround

Comment: Any way would be great. :) Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/madrian/pk9b6mqa/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 0.9.4.beta.37

```
yadcf.initOnDtXhrComplete(function() { 
    yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[4, $("#yadcf-filter--mytable-4 option:eq(1)").val()]], true); 
    //third argument is true so that the filter will happen immediately
});
```

Here is the docs for the `initOnDtXhrComplete`

> - initOnDtXhrComplete
>                 Description:        Allows to set a callback function to be called after dt xhr finishes
>                 Arguments:          function to do some logic
>                 Usage example:      yadcf.initOnDtXhrComplete(function() {
>     $("#yadcf-filter--example-0").multiselect('refresh'); });

[See working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/6cm81uLv/6/)

Comment: It doesn't work properly. I updated data source (I added week 3/2020 for "drilling guide" item). Now, on your example 3/2020 is the first element, but others are still showing up + sorting by Likes is broken (as you see it's active, but it's not sorted by Likes). Screenshot: https://hopp.mihalko.eu/36qMSev

Comment: For some reason I doesn't even see the new week (3/2020) in the selector.

Comment: you can test in your Jsfiddle, I updated only the data source: https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/6cm81uLv/6/

Comment: I got it working on my local setup. Super. One more question: it is possible to set "selected" for the selected option? Now it's empty at page load.

Comment: I thought something like this, but isn't working from here: ```yadcf.initOnDtXhrComplete(function() { 
      yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[4, $("#yadcf-filter--mytable-4 option:eq(1)").val()]], true);
      $("#yadcf-filter--mytable-4").val($("#yadcf-filter--mytable-4 option:eq(1)").val());
   });```

Comment: provide a new jsfiddle... not sure that I got you

Comment: For some reason I can't make it work properly on jsfiddle, but here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/madrian/nfgotr0j/3/. But it doesn't work properly: result is not filtered. Weird. The good news is that it's work on the actual website: http://bow.thingiverse.ml. The only problem on the actual website is, that the select is empty:  https://hopp.mihalko.eu/2QTEyNP.

Comment: Try using different dt versions (older / newest) , for some reason `table_arg.fnDraw` inside `exFilterColumn` reseting select filter value...

Comment: Hello Daniel, I tried all versions to 1.10.0 (released in 2014), all have the same problem. What do you think, it is worth to report as a bug, or not?

Comment: I remember I had something similar with the draw function, I guess it worth asking, post here the forum url in case...

Comment: There is some progress started, I guess. https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59851/possible-bug-in-the-draw-function

Comment: Looks like there is a bug with initOnDtXhrComplete, it doesn't seem to work with server side processing. Do you have idea for any workaround?

Comment: it's on http://bow.thingiverse.ml/index.html (init.dt event as was suggested on datatables forum) . https://bow.thingiverse.ml/index2.html (initOnDtXhrComplete as suggested by you)